# Is it possible to receive a Schengen visa as an unemployed person if I have a sponsor?

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-of-funds

I met someone I really like on the net. He asked me to visit him in Norway where he is a citizen. He will be going on pension in July and wants to use the time to show me around. I am unemployed and can only stay for a few weeks. Will his pension be enough as proof of income? I am South African.

Comment: Strictly speaking, having a job is not a requirement for a schengen visa.

Answer (score 4):

If you are unemployed and the premise of your visit is romantic and you have no real acquaintance with your friend, they will refuse unless your application is really high quality and his invitation is massively convincing.

You didn't tell us his pension, but they will look at his standing also.  They will also check his sponsorship history.